# how to start the game without entering into menu screen

Tags: c#, unity

i am trying to play the game without entering to menu screen. i have placed only one scene. my ui and game both is placed within the same scene. in my game over screen i have two buttons. for home button i give

```
Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
```

by this code is loading the scene from the begning and its working perfectly. in my another button i want to play the game direcly without showing the main menu. so i tried

```
Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
launchGame();
```

but after loading the level my second line launchGame() is not working. how can i solve this problem? please help

Comment: The first line is reloading the scene. Everything in that scene is destroyed. So launchGame() call will not fire. Depending on what you're trying to do, you could make that call from Start() method

Comment: if I do call from start, then every time the game ll start without displaying main menu right?

Comment: @SanSolo Small detail: launchGame() will be called, it's just unlikely to work as intended, since like you said, the previous scene is already destroyed.

Comment: @piojo can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ManojBalajiM I posted an answer. But what I meant by my comment is to point out a common mistake: Unity doesn't follow magical or hidden rules. Unity programming is normal programming, and in normal programming, functions don't exit in the middle, unless you exceptions are thrown or you `return` early. So when you call `Destroy(this)`, `LoadLevel()`, or other seemingly magical function, the rest of the code block will still run.

Comment: @piojo thanks for your reply i got some idea after seeing your reply now I am trying to execute, After execution i ll update my status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two features you could use to solve this problem: static variables, and `DontDestroyOnload()`. A static variable is not tied to a certain object, so it will not be erased/inaccessible after reloading the scene. For example, you could add this to a "GameManager" component in your scene:

```
enum GameState { Menus, Battle };
public static GameState gameState = GameState.Menus;

void Awake()
{
    if (gameState == GameState.Battle)
        launchGame();
}
```

And your button would set this new state before reloading the scene:

```
GameManager.gameState = GameManager.GameState.Battle;
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
```

The other method to have game logic continue running is to have a game object and script that persists when the level is reloaded. To stay persistent, that script must call `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)`. This technique is more complicated, since after reload, you'll end up with two objects in your scene. You'll need care to ensure the correct object is used. (A loader script is sometimes used for this, so the manager will never be duplicated in the scene--the loader will simply need to be smart enough not to load when not needed.)